# HTML and CSS Background doesn't display?

Tags: javascript, html, css, material-design, css-animations

I am trying to get an image to display an image using css background image, but I am not able to get the image to render.

CSS IS HERE:

```
body{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
   background-image: url(/steampunk/wallpaperSteampunk_B.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
}
```

HTML IS HERE:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="Main.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <script src="jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="JQUERY%20Main.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="box">
            <div id="main"></div>
```

---

Everything from the CSS works except the BG image, What am I missing here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you need `'` around your bg path

Comment: @JoeWarner — No. There are no characters in the URL that would require quotes.

Comment: The most likely reason for the problem is *you got the URL wrong*. Use the Network tab if your browser's developer tools to make sure the image is being requested and to see how the server is responding to the request (e.g. it might be Forbidden or Not Found).

Comment: @wasaach Are you using a web server or just a plain html file?

Answer (score 0):

In case you are just using an html file opened within a browser, you need to make the url **relative to the file** and skip the `/` at the beginning of the url. Like so:

```
background-image: url(steampunk/wallpaperSteampunk_B.jpg);
```

In case you run your code within a web server, your url is correct and will just work because it is **relative to the root** of the host:

```
background-image: url(/steampunk/wallpaperSteampunk_B.jpg);
```

Answer (score -2):

Except for the `'` on background image path, you also need to set a height.

Comment: @th.stamond It's not required to put the url in quotes.

Comment: There is no need to set a height. By default, the background of the body element is transferred to the html element and applied to the viewport or page, whichever is larger.